# Trying to call a function inside a for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ill post the code in a second. I am making a call to a service to pull data back. I get the data in an array and each one needs to make another call to another service. so I set my code up like so:

```
Services.getHelo({
    assetSurfaceId: $scope.assetSurfaceId
}).then(function (resp) {
    delete resp["$promise"];
    delete resp["$resolved"];

    $scope.entity.helo = resp;

    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.entity.helo.length; i++) {
        heloCall($scope.entity.helo, i);
        initHelo($scope.entity.helo, i);
    }
});
```

After I delete the promise and $resolved I start my for loop to call to my other functions. the initHelo function just builds a list for me and gets the vars ready for the next call into it. the heloCall makes the other calls i need.

Here is the helocall code:

```
var heloCall = function (r, i) {
    jQuery("#helo").mask("Loading Surface Asset Helos...");
    Services.getStatus({
        toEntityId: r[i].assetHeloId,
        toEntityTypeId: widget_consts.ASSET_HELICOPTER
    }).then(function (s) {
        delete s["$promise"];
        delete s["$resolved"];
        $scope.entity.helo[i].status = [];
        $scope.entity.helo[i].status = s;
        if (s[0].statusLkupShortDesc === "PMC" || s[0].statusLkupShortDesc === "NMC") {
            Services.getReason({
                toEntityId: s[0].statusId
            }).then(function (reason) {
                delete reason["$promise"];
                delete reason["$resolved"];
                if (reason) {
                    $scope.entity.helo[i].status.reason = [];
                    $scope.entity.helo[i].status.reason = reason;
                    initHelo($scope.entity.helo, i);

                }
            });
            Services.getComment({
                toEntityId: r[i].assetHeloId
            }).then(function (info) {
                delete info["$promise"];
                delete info["$resolved"];
                if (info) {
                    $scope.entity.helo[i].status.remark = {};
                    $scope.entity.helo[i].status.remark = info;
                    initHelo($scope.entity.helo, i);
                }
            });
        }
        initHelo($scope.entity.helo, i);
        jQuery("#helo").unmask();
    });
};
```

I do a check after the status call is made to make sure it is a status that Would have reasons with it and if it is i make the calls i need.

My issue is this only works when it wants to. I am not sure what i screwed up. I have been trying to get it to work right all day.

It has worked many times for me but I need it to work all the time.
Is there a better way to do this?
I actually have another call in this same file that is set up the same way and works each time with no issues

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to run a check to make sure that the length of the array returned from the service was not 0. it would cause issues depending on witch call was returned first. after I put this check it in runs fine.